# How to show multiple condition with mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with with my query. I have this data : Check this out here is full data and my table. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f440d7/1

Please i hope you can help me.

My expected result should be like this :

```
|PartID           | IdMesin |ket1                |ket2     |Ket3|
|----------       |-------- |----------------    |---------|    |            
|AELE-00071-XX-KGX|BS 150U  |-                   |1.00 Tes1|-   |
|GCXX-MX070-XX-KGX|BS 320F  |0.50 Tes3, 2.00 Tes4|0.50 Tes2|-   |
```

I hope you can help me to fix this problem. Anyhelp can be appreciated.

Comment: `Please help me to check where query that is wrong` ... you need to answer this yourself in your question to us.

Comment: i have edited my question, can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`case when` should be used in `group_concat`:

```
SELECT partid,
       idmesin,
       COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN idshift = '1' THEN CONCAT(ROUND(
                TIME_TO_SEC(
                MAKETIME(
                durasi + 0,
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(durasi, 'Jam ', - 1) + 0, 0)) / 3600, 2), ' ',
                keterangandowntime) end), '-') ket1,
       COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN idshift = '2' THEN CONCAT(ROUND(
                TIME_TO_SEC(
                MAKETIME(
                durasi + 0,
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(durasi, 'Jam ', - 1) + 0, 0)) / 3600, 2), ' ',
                keterangandowntime) end), '-') ket2,
       COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN idshift = '3' THEN CONCAT(ROUND(
                TIME_TO_SEC(
                MAKETIME(
                durasi + 0,
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(durasi, 'Jam ', - 1) + 0, 0)) / 3600, 2), ' ',
                keterangandowntime) end), '-') ket3
FROM   trans_lhpdtdw
WHERE  divisiid = 'IJ001'
       AND tanggal = '2017-11-20'
       AND idlocation LIKE '%3%'
GROUP  BY partid,
          idmesin
```

See [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f440d7/17) in SQLFiddle.